# User Warning: Failed to save key %KEY% of type Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata: Cannot serialize Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient

Tags: symfony5

**My Question**

Is there a way to use Symfony Dependency Injection during the unserilize process in Symfony caching? I need to exclude a property in the __sleep magic method and add it during the __wakeup method call.

**Overview:**

I'm getting DEBUG logging out from the Symfony framework. I'm have several entities that uses the Doctrine ORM CustomIdGenerator. My custom id generator is a class that includes the HttpClientInterface passsed in with the container Dependency Injection.

**The Issue**

When Symfony caches the Entities it's including the class meta data. This meta data includes the CustomIdGenerator that has the HttpClientInterface client. The serializer calls the __sleep() magic method on the the CustomIdGenerator class and it's properties. Since the HttpClientInterface instance variable is a property of the CustomIdGenerator it's being serialized also. There is a __sleep() function in the CurlHttpClient that throws the exception if called.

**What I've tried**

I tried including the __sleep() function and returning the properties other than the HttpClientInterface. This stops the DEBUG logging but I cannot use the __wakeup() method because the client was injected via constructor Depedency Injection.

**Environment:**

PHP 8.0.6

Symfony: 5.3

**ERROR**

> 21:03:44 DEBUG     [php] User Warning: Failed to save key
> "App__Entity__MyEntity__CLASSMETADATA__" of
> type Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata: Cannot serialize
> Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient

```
[
  "exception" => Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\SilencedErrorContext^ {
    +count: 1
    -severity: E_USER_WARNING
    trace: {
      ./vendor/symfony/cache/CacheItem.php:189 { …}
      ./vendor/symfony/cache/Adapter/ArrayAdapter.php:356 { …}
    }
  }
]
```

**Entity Property**

```
    /**
     * The id is generated from a remote ticket server.
     * @var string
     */
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\Column(type: "string", length: 11, unique: true),
        ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "CUSTOM"),
        ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: "App\Utility\Id\Generator\SystemIdGenerator")
    ]
    protected string $id;
```

**Code throwing the exception:**

```
    // CLASS: \Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient

    public function __sleep()
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Cannot serialize '.__CLASS__);
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?